# Parse Server: Can not find sender for push type android

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

I do send push notifications with my `parse-server` like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "deviceType": {
            "$in": [
              "ios"
            ]
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "title": "The Shining",
          "alert": "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy."
        }
      }'\   https://myserver.com/parse/push
```

In the logs I always see this error message:

```
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: Can not find sender for push type android, {"where":{"deviceType":{"$in":["ios"]}},"data":{"title":"The Shining","badge":"1","alert":"All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy."}}
```

The device does receive the push notification just fine though.

I do not send push notifications to android devices. There is not even one registered. I also have not configured android push in my parse server configuration. There is only one single iOS device registered at the parse server.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it just tells U that it doesnt know how to send Push for Android. You can get rid of this error if you define the push for android with blank strings...

```
"android": {
           "senderId": "...",
           "apiKey": "..."
           },
```

Comment: Good to know. But why does it even try to send push to android if there is no keys defined?

Comment: I think it doesnt try to send it, It is maybe just a notification that you did not defined android pushes